# How do I install driver for Radeon Mobility HD 3650?

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, radeon, 14.10

I was trying to install driver for my graphics card, I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and when I install driver from support.amd.com log file says that i don't have kernel headers (version.h file) in /lib/modules/3.16.0-25-generic/build/include/linux/version.h -but I have kernel headers installed! How to make it work?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Install Linux Generic Headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Install the Drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

OR

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

OR (for AMD dual GFX)

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

OR

```
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
```

REBOOT!

To confirm the drivers are working:

fglrxinfo

Output must be similar to:

```
fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 3000M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.3.0)

Comment: Try: 

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati 

Make sure you select Usina ATI: http://i.imgur.com/m38FhN4.png